# How can I force the browser to scroll down to show all elements with "absolute" or "fixed" positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, scroll

I have a div element that "hovers" above the body of the page:

```
<body>
<div id="this_element_hovers" class="like_a_dialogue_box" style="position:fixed">
    POPUP CONTENT
</div>
</body>
```

The problem is, when #this_element_hovers is longer than the height of the window, the browser will not scroll to show the entire dialogue box/popup. How can I make the browser scroll to show the entire dialogue box?

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2):

According to your requirdment adjust height and width of div and set overflow property scroll

```
<div id="this_element_hovers" class="like_a_dialogue_box" style="position:fixed;width:200px;height:200px;overflow:scroll;">
    POPUP CONTENT
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you css itself says that it is fixed and it cannot move and moreover the length of it is also big.

i would suggest you to place your content of the fixed div in a scrollable div with **overflow:auto** css attribute and make the height of the div smaller so that it is viewable on the screen.